# How to add specific files from a series of folders to an array?

Tags: python, file

So far I've managed to compile all of the files from a series of folders using the following:

```
path = r'C:\Users\keefr\Documents\Data\Pulse Characterisation\sample 7' 
subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]

for sub in subfolders:
    for f in os.listdir(sub):
        print(f)
        files = [i for i in f if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(f,'*.txt')) and 'data' in f]
```

Where f prints out the names of all of the files. What I want to do is take only certain files from this (starts with 'data' and is a .txt file) and put these in an array called `files`. The last line in the above code is where I tried to do this but whenever I print files it's still an empty array. Any ideas where I'm going wrong and how to fix it?

**Update**
I've made some progress, I changed the last line to:

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(sub,f)) and 'data' in f:
    files.append(f)
```

So I now have an array with the correct file names. The problem now is that there's a mix of .meta, .index and .txt files and I only want the .txt files. What's the best way to filter out the other types of files?

Comment: Side note: lists are not arrays.

Comment: What is `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(f,'*.txt'))` supposed to do?

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend using pathlib instead of the os module for this.

Comment: Yes I just noticed the typo, my bad.  It's to get all the .txt files in f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably do it like this. Considering f is the filename, and is a string, python has functions `startswith()` and `endswith()` that can be applied to specifically meet your criteria of **starting with `data` and ending with `.txt`**. If we find such a file, we append it to file_list. If you want the full path in file_list, I trust you are able to make that modification.

```
import os
path = r'C:\Users\keefr\Documents\Data\Pulse Characterisation\sample 7'
subfolders = [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]

file_list = []
for sub in subfolders:
    for f in os.listdir(sub):
        if (f.startswith("data") and f.endswith(".txt")):
            file_list.append(f)
print(file_list)
```